# How to display all data from a table?

Tags: php, mysql, html, web

Well i've been searching google, but I still can't find out how to do this.

I'm a beginner in php so i'm really stumped.

Anyways what I need to do is get all the data from a table and display it on my page.

Like

Contents of row 1

Contents of row 2

etc.

Well that's nice, get down voted for asking for help.

Comment: are you kidding that you didn't get a single example for [this](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&q=mysql+php+connection+example&oq=mysql+php+connect&aq=1&aqi=g8g-m1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=8342l13041l4l14049l17l17l0l1l1l0l195l2039l6.10l16l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=fdf16cdc3281d32a&biw=1024&bih=661) & [this](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much PHP DB access 101

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDbName', 'username', 'password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM a_table');
$stmt->execute();

$resultSet = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($resultSet as $idx => $row) {
    echo '<p>Contents of row ', $idx + 1, '</p><dl>';
    foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
        printf('<dt>%s</dt><dd>%s</dd>',
               htmlspecialchars($col),
               htmlspecialchars($val));
    }
    echo '</dl>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help you

`print_r()` displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans.

`print_r()`, `var_dump()` and `var_export()` will also show protected and private properties of objects with PHP 5. Static class members will not be shown.

Remember that `print_r()` will move the array pointer to the end. Use `reset()` to bring it back to beginning.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 1):

I think google should have given you your answer since this is a rather easy to answer question, but when starting, you don't always know what to search for.

Anyways, hope this helps.

```
<?php
// connect with you database, returns boolean so you know if you succeeded or not
$con = mysql_connect($database,$username,$password);
if(!$scon){
    die('Could not connect to database'); // Stop execution if connection fails
    }

//create your query
$query = "Place your database query here";

//get the results
$result = mysql_query($query);

//now you want to go through each row of the result table and echo the contents, or
//use them for whatever reason
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['field_you_want_to_display'];
    echo $row['another_field_you_want_to_display']; //You see where this is going
    }

//After doing what you want, close the connection to the database
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Also, you may want to take a look at the [documentation of php](http://php.net/docs.php) for find out what functions you have not seen before do.